# Fabric8 maven plugin is complaining about an deployment config issue

Tags: maven, openshift, fabric8

I'm getting this error message when I perform `mvn fabric8:resource-apply`:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.38:resource-apply (default-cli) on project tdev-wsec-service: Failed to create DeploymentConfig from openshift.yml. io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://minishift.t-systems.net:8443/apis/apps.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/myproject/deploymentconfigs. Message: DeploymentConfig "tdev-wsec-service" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].name: Invalid value: "com.tsystems.iberia-tdev-wsec-service": a DNS-1123 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is 'a-z0-9?'). Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=422, details=StatusDetails(causes=[StatusCause(field=spec.template.spec.containers[0].name, message=Invalid value: "com.tsystems.iberia-tdev-wsec-service": a DNS-1123 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is 'a-z0-9?'), reason=FieldValueInvalid, additionalProperties={})], group=null, kind=DeploymentConfig, name=tdev-ws...

In short:

> DeploymentConfig "tdev-wsec-service" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].name: Invalid value: "com.tsystems.iberia-tdev-wsec-service": a DNS-1123 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name', or '123-abc', regex used for validation is 'a-z0-9?')

I'm trying to push into my openshift these resources:

[image]

fabric8 plugin is complaining about something I don't quite figure out what's wrong. For example, fabric8 plugin is telling me that there's something wrong inside deployment config, but `wsec-deployment.yaml` content is really straighforward:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    configmap.fabric8.io/update-on-change: ${project.artifactId}
  labels:
    name: wsec
  name: wsec
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: wsec
    version: ${project.version}
    provider: fabric8
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: wsec
        version: ${project.version}
        provider: fabric8
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
          valueFrom:
           configMapKeyRef:
             name: wsec-configmap
             key: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
        name: wsec
        image: ${docker.image}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Parent `pom.xml` most fabric8 relevant part:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tsystems.iberia</groupId>
    <artifactId>t-devhub</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC1</spring-cloud.version>

        <fabric8-maven-plugin.version>3.5.38</fabric8-maven-plugin.version>
        <fabric8.build.strategy>docker</fabric8.build.strategy>
        <fabric8.build.mode>openshift</fabric8.build.mode>

        <docker.from>docker.io/fabric8/java-jboss-openjdk8-jdk:1.2</docker.from>
        <docker.assemblyDescriptorRef>artifact</docker.assemblyDescriptorRef>
        <docker.image>${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</docker.image>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${fabric8-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mode>${fabric8.build.mode}</mode>
                    <enricher>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>spring-boot-health-check</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </enricher>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>${docker.image}</name>
                            <build>
                                <from>${docker.from}</from>
                                <assembly>
                                    <targetDir>/deployments</targetDir>
                                    <descriptorRef>${docker.assemblyDescriptorRef}</descriptorRef>
                                </assembly>
                                <env>
                                    <JAVA_APP_JAR>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</JAVA_APP_JAR>
                                </env>
                            </build>
                            <run>
                                <ports>
                                    <port>8080:8080</port>
                                </ports>
                            </run>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Fabric8 generator tried to assign a name to your first container, but the name is invalid. Could you post your `pom.xml`, particularly those configurations for fabric8 maven plugin?

Comment: I edited the post adding fabric8 parent `pom.xml` related sections.

Answer (score 0):

I found that having a more than one dash ( - ) in he  arttifactId caused the issue.

```
    <groupId>com.something</groupId>
      <artifactId>servicename-microservice-something</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
    <name>servicename</name>
```

Changed artifactId to

```
    <artifactId>servicename</artifactId>
```

and it worked.